# phone picture overlay iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, frontend

So I am trying to have a picture of an iPhone X (the image has a transparent background and the phone screen itself is transparent too ) with a YouTube video playing inside of it. The the way I attempted to do it was have the iPhone image take up the entirety of a div and then using absolute positioning to position the iframe under the image. I tried to use the z-index to have the iframe be behind the image (with the image essentially being an overflay), but what ends up happening is that the image's transparent background only shows the background color, not the iframe behind it.

```
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div style="position: relative">
          <img
              src="images/phones/iphone-blank-transperant.svg"
              style="z-index: 999;"
          />
          <iframe
              style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; top: 7.5%; width: 75.7%; left:12.65%; height: 82%;"
              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IzYp6cqTiAw"
              allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
              allowfullscreen
          ></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Once again, I would like the iframe be visible under the phone image. I have attached an image as a reference (I had to convert it to a PNG in order to upload it)[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a **position:absolute** in your img styling

The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

see: [CSS Positions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR3kw.png" style="z-index:1 ;position:absolute"   />
```

https://codepen.io/moseleygj/pen/QWQRGwg

```
 <div class="col-md-4" style="background:grey">
    <div style="position: absolute;border:">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR3kw.png" style="z-index:1 ;position:absolute"   />
      <iframe
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TdFL1qZ8-dg"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen style="z-index: -1; position: relative; ; width:310px ; left:53px;height:673px ;top:29px;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).